cannot access localhost from Docker container
I followed this tutorial step by step : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZGu-9KQVsE

I created a Dockerfile :

FROM ubuntu:jammy
RUN : \
    && apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        curl \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


I built the docker image :

docker build -t mycurl .


I ran the image using

docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway --rm -ti mycurl bash


I started a local server using

python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...


But when I try to access it from my container, i get this timeout :

root@da4d8b1f4ae4:/# curl host.docker.internal:8000
curl: (28) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 8000 after 133451 ms: Connection timed out

My /etc/hosts is :
root@da4d8b1f4ae4:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.1  host.docker.internal
172.17.0.2  da4d8b1f4ae4

Any idea why ? I am on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

I solved my problem by running this :
sudo ufw allow 8000

